# 15 puzzle background image JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, css

My tiles (divs) in the 15 puzzle are placed correctly, but all have the same image which is the top left corner of my background image. How can I set the div to take a specific position of the background image applied to it? Most probably a CSS question.

Comment: Give us some code to work with..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a CSS question, and the answer is background-position.  See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: Second the w3fools comment :D. Here's links to the [W3 resource on Background properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties) or the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position)

Answer (score 0):

use background position - it's a css property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp